# Don't map property in SubClass

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to tell Fluent NHibernate not to map a property in a `SubClassMap` which is defined in it's parent's `ClassMap`? So:

```
public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        this.Map(x => x.Id);
        this.HasManyToMany(x => x.Somethings)
            .Table("ParentSomethings")
            .ParentKeyColumn("ParentId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("SomethingId");
        this.DiscriminateSubClassesOn("Foo");
    }
}

public class ChildMap : SubclassMap<Child> // with Child : Parent
{
    this.DiscriminatorValue("Child");
    this.DontMap(x => x.Somethings); // fictional method
}
```

Comment: Won't this break the Liskov principle? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle? How can you handle `child as a parent` if it does not have the correct (expected) mapping?

Comment: @RadimKöhler The `Somethings` in `Child` is handled in a non-database way but needs to be for `Parent` but I need to be able to do `Query<Parent>()` to get both `Parent`s and `Child`s. So in terms of the code, the LSP is not broken.

Comment: Your map are wrong. `ChildMap` needs to extends `SubClassMap<Child>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this, your map are wrong, you need to create a ClassMap to Parent, and don't map this property "something", and create two differents mappings for children, one that contains "something" property and one that does not contain.

Comment: Thanks but I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'IgnoreProperty'"

Comment: So I editted my answer, verify if its possible to change in your mappings.

Comment: Yeah I think I need to go down this path. Thanks.